# Cumulative sum with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
set @cumulativeSum := 0;
select
  (@cumulativeSum:= @cumulativeSum + (count(distinct `ce`.URL, `ce`.`IP`))) as `uniqueClicks`,
  cast(`ce`.`dt` as date) as `createdAt`
from (SELECT DISTINCT min((date(CODE_EVENTS.CREATED_AT))) dt, CODE_EVENTS.IP, CODE_EVENTS.URL
      FROM CODE_EVENTS
      GROUP BY CODE_EVENTS.IP, CODE_EVENTS.URL) as ce
      join ATTACHMENT on `ce`.URL = ATTACHMENT.`ID`
where ATTACHMENT.`USER_ID` = 6
group by cast(`ce`.`dt` as date)
  ORDER BY ce.URL;
```

It works almost ok, I would like to have as result set a date and amount of cumulative sum as uniqueClicks, the problem is that in my result set it is not added up together.

```
uniqueClicks createdAt
1            2018-02-01
3            2018-02-03
1            2018-02-04
```

and I'd like to have

```
uniqueClicks createdAt
1            2018-02-01
4            2018-02-03
5            2018-02-04
```

Comment: Does this have to be in a query? This is one of the few cases where I would opt for: Maybe handle this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can obtain a rolling sum of the unique clicks without needing to resort to dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT
    t1.CREATED_AT,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.uniqueClicks) FROM
     (
         SELECT CREATED_AT, COUNT(DISTINCT IP, URL) uniqueClicks
         FROM CODE_EVENTS
         GROUP BY CREATED_AT
     ) t2
     WHERE t2.CREATED_AT <= t1.CREATED_AT) uniqueClicksRolling
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CREATED_AT
    FROM CODE_EVENTS
) t1
ORDER BY t1.CREATED_AT;
```

The subquery aliased as `t2` computes the number of unique clicks on each given day which appears in your table.  The distinct count of IP and URL is what determines the number of clicks.  We can then subquery this intermediate table and sum clicks for all days up and including the current date.  This is essentially cursor style action, and can replace your use of session variables.

Comment: wouldnt it be a slow query with lots of records in table CODE_EVENTS?

Comment: @filemonczyk Yes, this is an N^2 approach and it might not be so performant.  But, if you are using it over reasonably small time ranges, it might not be a problem for you.  If you need performance, then yes your approach with session variables is probably the way to do.  I just saw a way to simplify your query and went with it.

Comment: i have to be ready for lots of record in table n^2 might be killing the request

Comment: @filemonczyk Actually, now that I think more about your problem, you might want to use a trigger after insert to continually tally the clicks coming in.  In other words, you maintain a click count for each day dynamically.  Then, when you query, you are just reading a bunch of already-computed static data.