# Mysql cumulative summation based on hours

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

I have a mysql table and i need a query to have cumulative sum :

```
hour  col1    col2

00     1000  app
00     400   ck
01     100   app
01     100   ck
```

I need like this :

```
 hour  app    ck

00     1000   400
01     1100   500
```

tried but i am new to mysql so not able to crack looking at other examples:

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql Version 14.14

Comment: Highest MySQL version is 8. That might be your distribution. What do you get from `SELECT @@version`?

Comment: This functionality is quite new in MySQL, coming in with version 8.0.2

Comment: SELECT @@version 5.6.25-73.1-log
 But if you know the functionality how to use to cumulative sum please let me now that

Comment: Just solve the problem in python with a simple loop.

Comment: nope i need in a quer y of mysql::
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618771/cumulative-sum-with-mysql" check this ...i am not getting how to implement in my code

Comment: Since you're using MySQL5.6 you can't use window functions (`OVER...`). But you can use the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql

Comment: Nick i m new to mysql can you implement the query usinmg my table which would be better and give me the query

Comment: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tests;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tests(`hour` char(2) not null primary key, col1 int not null, col2 int not null);

INSERT tests(`hour`, col1, col2)
VALUES ('00',1000,900),('01',400,100),('02',100,300),('03',100,400);

SELECT * FROM tests;

SET @col1=0;
SET @col2=0;

UPDATE tests t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT `hour`, @col1:=col1+@col1 AS col1_sum,  @col2:=col2+@col2 AS col2_sum
  FROM tests
  ORDER BY hour) s
ON t.`hour`=s.`hour`
SET t.col1=s.col1_sum,
  t.col2=s.col2_sum
;

SELECT * FROM tests;

Comment: Can not format the query in comments. But the one in the above comment should work

Answer (score 0):

Basic older version of SQL, joining the table against itself.

Something like this

```
SELECT a.hour, SUM(b.col1), SUM(b.col2)
FROM sometable a
INNER JOIN sometable b
ON a.hour >= b.hour 
GROUP BY a.hour
```